# Kivy- All dynamically created buttons (in for loop) return the same argument

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make a password locker app.

The problem I'm facing is I want to create a button for each username, and then perform a function when the button is clicked, which takes different arguments depending on the button clicked.
**But whichever button is clicked, regardless of it's own username, the function associated with it always takes the argument of the last button created.** I want to know why this happens.

My code for creating the buttons and copying the password for that username:

```
class CopyCredentialWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CopyCredentialWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1), do_scroll_y=True, do_scroll_x=False, scroll_timeout=55, bar_width=10)
        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid.bind(minimum_height=self.grid.setter('height'))
    def on_enter(self):
        button_list = []
        for i in self.manager.credentials:
            button_list.append(Button(text=i[8:], size_hint_y=None, height=40, on_release=lambda x: self.do_accordingly(i)))
            self.grid.add_widget(button_list[-1])
        self.scroll.add_widget(self.grid)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.scroll)
    def delete_dropdown(self):
        self.grid.clear_widgets()
        self.scroll.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.grid.remove_widget(self.scroll)
    def do_accordingly(self, account_name):
        credentials = self.manager.credentials
        password = credentials[account_name]
        password = password.encode()
        password = self.manager.f.decrypt(password)
        password = password.decode()
        MyApp.displaypassword = password
        pyperclip.copy(password)
        ok = PopupContent()
        popup = Popup(title='Password Copied', content=ok,
              auto_dismiss=False, size_hint=(1,1))
        ok.closebutton.bind(on_release=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()
        self.delete_dropdown()
        self.manager.current = "Options"
```

self.manager.credentials is a dictionary with usernames as keys and passwords as values.
So for example,

```
self.manager.credentials = {"one":"1","two":"3","third_username":"thirdpassword"}
```

Here 3 buttons will be created with names one, two, and third_username. **(Note that in my code the Button's text is i[8:], that is because I have a custom alias for each username, and it is 7 characters long.)**

But whenever I click the first/second button (button named 'one'/'two'), the function *do_accordingly* always gets the argument of the third button, namely 'third_username', which always returns the password for the third button, regardless of which button is clicked.

Any Idea as to why this happens?
Thank you.

My .kv code (in case it matters):

```
<CopyCredentialWindow>:
    name: "CopyCredentials"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
        AnchorLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Click here to Go Back\nSelect account to copy:"
                font_size: 20
                color: .4, .4, .8, 1
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "Options"
                    root.delete_dropdown()
```

Edit- Note that the text of the button is correctly appearing, but the function just does not work as expected.

Edit 2:
**I got it working thanks to- Lothric**
Here is the code that got in working:
Inside the for loop:

```
            button_list.append(Button(text=i[8:], size_hint_y=None, height=40, on_release=lambda x, cred=i: self.do_accordingly(cred)))
            self.grid.add_widget(button_list[-1])
```

Comment: Does the same thing happens if you use `partial(self.do_accordingly, i)` for the `on_release` callback?

Comment: Yes. I've tried all things. Using partial makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's common problem and solution is to create widgets in a list or in a dict. You created list with separate buttons and you don't use it, try this:

```
        for i in self.manager.credentials:
            button_list.append(Button(text=i[8:], size_hint_y=None, height=40, on_release=lambda x, cred=i: self.do_accordingly(cred)))
            self.grid.add_widget(button_list[-1])
```

Comment: @KrYmZiN ok, I've edited my answer, try it once more

Comment: @KrYmZiN you're welcome, and by the way  it's not Kivy problem, it's Python issue, so you can have that with any other framework when you use lambda in a loop :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured, but since It's based on kivy I tagged it too.